# chart.js in ionic/angular app compile errors

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ng2-charts

### My goal

I am trying to draw a simple bar chart with a goal line.

### My problem in summary

Installing/using ng2-charts seems to be OK for the barchart itself, but I'm struggling to get the [annotation-plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/) to even compile without errors.

### Details of the problem

I used [Digamber's tutorial](https://www.positronx.io/angular-chart-js-tutorial-with-ng2-charts-examples/) to get started.

[image: Bar Chart]

The image above is the bar chart, working as desired. I realize this using this snippet inside of the typescript file for the associated page:

```
  barChartLabels: Label[] = [''];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartPlugins = [];
  barChartLegend = false;
  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [450], label: 'Forecast', backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,75,190)', barThickness: 50 },
    { data: [750], label: 'Invoiced', backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,200,200)', barThickness: 50  },
    { data: [1250], label: 'Received', backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,200,100)', barThickness: 50 },
  ];
```

So far, so good.  But now I want to draw a vertical line at an arbitrary point, say 2400 for an example.  I am trying to use the [charts.js plugin annotation.](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/)  So I have to include

```
import * as pluginAnnotations from 'chartjs-plugin-annotation';
```

at the top of the file, and then include it in the chart options:

```
barChartLabels: Label[] = [''];
  barChartType: ChartType = 'horizontalBar';
  barChartPlugins = [pluginAnnotations];     <<<<<<<<
  barChartLegend = false;
  barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [450], label: 'Forecast', backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,75,190)', barThickness: 50 },
    { data: [750], label: 'Invoiced', backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,200,200)', barThickness: 50  },
    { data: [1250], label: 'Received', backgroundColor: 'rgb(0,200,100)', barThickness: 50 },
  ];
```

But whenever I do so, I get this error at compile time:

```
Failed to compile.

node_modules/chartjs-plugin-annotation/types/index.d.ts:1:10 - error TS2305: Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Plugin'.

1 import { Plugin, ChartType } from 'chart.js';
```

I have installed the plugin with

```
npm install chartjs-plugin-annotation
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `CDN` for both `Plugin` and `Chartjs`;

Comment: Would you say a bit more?  Why CDN for this?  How does it solve this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: because its working in my project through CDN. ng2-chart is not updates i think and with cdn you can use latest version of chatjs.